# Why are game questions on SU just closed and not deleted?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

This is a thought that came to mind after seeing the daily couple gaming questions that come into SU. If the rules state that most gaming questions are not within the scope of the site, why don't we just delete those questions instead of close them and leave them laying around?

Just for reference, link to one of Jeff's answers: [Do closed questions ever get deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/do-closed-question-ever-get-deleted/5045#5045)

Comment: I have to admit I find it interesting that right after I close a question I will get hit with a string of down votes, sometimes on all my accounts on all four sites. Really find it hilarious actually.

Comment: @Diago: Just watch, a user is going to start a website" Diagoisadouchebag.com"

Comment: Well if the negativity has as much success for me as for Jeff - Go for it. Even redirect it to my site if you want. If the exchange rate wasn't killer I would do it myself :)

Comment: Good thing users can't see all the flags I throw on those questions then. :)

Comment: EBGreen - But I can :)

Comment: @Diago: Welcome to my experience. You should see my serial downvotes.

Comment: @RichB I feel for you. I see the flags :)

Comment: I need to get up to the 10k club at least for SU.

Comment: Funnily I am not in the 10K club anywhere. Sad really. I have given up on SO. I am just not fast enough.

Comment: You guys most likely delete more than I think, because I would never see them to begin with much of the time.

Comment: @Diago perhaps I'll try to comment on some of those questions next times, I have enough rep to survive a serial downvote and my SO rep isn't even worth the trouble ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the type of game question.  If it relates to getting the game to run under certain conditions and specific hardware, it *might* be legitimate question and should therefore be reviewed.

Otherwise, if it's a "how do i g3ts sturcraft 4?" it's most likely to get shot at like a turkey before Thanksgiving and closed up like a car dealership.

Answer (score 1):

Valid point. However in the past some questions have been re-opened and allowed. Even Jeff himself closes them and doesn't delete them. In some cases there are a very gray area and other moderators may decide to re-open a question if they feel it is valid.

I have been under fire a lot lately for closing gaming and phone question irrelevant of the content, as I believe keeping just one question open makes it extremely hard to enforce a rule when others ask similar questions. This is becoming a very heated debate at the moment.

Comment: Adding a comment to the question might alleviate some of this.

Comment: Then direct them here and to the relevant thread.  That way they can voice their opinion.  Otherwise they'll just voice it the only way they know which is downvoting you.

Comment: Agreed - Often I do. However it does tend to get tiring with some of the abuse. However I have a thick skin and this is the internet. Someone is bound to be wrong :)

Comment: Why does "The internet is serious business" always seem like a relavant commment?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the leader board and I note that there are **no** 10k reputations on the site as yet. So only moderators can delete. Wait a couple of weeks...

Answer (score 0):

They are left there to mark the boundary that must not be crossed. Much as headhunters might mark their teritory with shrunken heads mounted on spears.